# Changing Exception type to base class

Tags: c#, class, exception, derived-class, mailkit

I have two projects. In one of them I use MailKit and it is responsible for all kinds of email.
Here I could get `SmtpCommandExceptions` or `SmtpProtocolExceptions` that are derived of `CommandException` which is derived of the normal `System.Exception`.
I want to give the exception to the other project without binding the complete MailKit into the other project. So I thought about getting the additional properties into strings, putting them together and send everything else back.

Is there any way of extracting the exception out of the derived class and throw away all additional methods, properties, and so on?

Comment: What really do you need? All the context and some additional properties, if any, or just error message?

Comment: For possibly later debugging it would be nice to have as much information as possible. Including stacktrace, data, and so on. But most of these are write protected, so I cannot simply copy them from the derived class to a newly made object of the base class.

Comment: Oh and there is an exception handling in the "base" project. So I have to transfer an exception.

Comment: Do you have `ProjectA->ProjectB->MailKit`? You can catch `Exception` in ProjectA without explicit dependance to MailKit. If you need additional information, catch `CommandException` in ProjectB and throw custom exception.

Comment: The Exception is not thrown to projectA, but put into some EventArgs and transferred that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The typical way to deal with this kind of problem is to wrap the exception in a custom exception class:

```
public class MyWrappedException : Exception
{
    public string MyProperty { get; }

    public MyWrappedException(string message, string myProperty, Exception innerException)
        : base(message, innerException)
    {
        MyProperty = myProperty;
    }
}
```

Called like:

```
  try
  {
      DoSomething();
  }
  catch(InvalidOperationException ex)
  {
      throw new MyWrappedException("Oups", "tried doing X", ex);
  }
```

This keeps the all the original exception information, but most of it will not be visible unless you use a debugger or it is included when converting to a string. You can select what properties you want to include in the wrapper. This lets you catch your wrapped exception without an direct dependency on mailkit.

Answer (score 1):

As far as stacktrace is concerned, you could just pass base Exception.
But if you want more information, specific to some exception class, I can think of one solution.

For example, create a class like:

```
public class ExceptionInfo
{
    public string Message {get;set;}
    public int SomeValue {get;set;}
    public double SomeOtherValue {get;set;}
    
    public readonly Exception OriginalException;
    
    public ExceptionInfo(Exception originalEx)
    {
        OriginalException = originalEx;
    }
}
```

Now, when you catch specific exception, you can serialize it like so:

```
catch(SmtpCommandException ex)
{
   ExceptionInfo info = ex.MakeExceptionInfo(); //this should be some helper method
   SendException(info);
}
```

Now, the solution is to create a helper method for each kind of exception, or just some generic method that would create your ErrorInfo with common exception values that you want to have. For example:

```
public static ExceptionInfo MakeExceptionInfo(this SmptCommandException ex)
{
    ExceptionInfo result = new ExceptionInfo(ex);
    result.SomeValue = ex.SomevalueFromOriginalException;

    return result;
}
```

Next, when you have your ExceptionInfo class you can send it to other parts of your application.

Firstly I thought that you could use serialization (for example json), but I thing that this solution is much more clearer. But requires some coding. Maybe you will come up with solution that combines my idea with json.